# Checkboxes, select all / none message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that checks the checkboxes who are checked and shows if they are all selected, none or a list of which ones.

The code works fine, but I think this very long, I am not expert in javascript.
Is there any way to make the shorter code?

```
var Desktop = $(".multiselect.desktop input[name$='[]']:checked").map(function() {return this.value;}).get().join(', ');

if(Desktop.split(', ').length == 4){ Desktop = 'All';}
else if(Desktop.length == 0){ Desktop = 'None';} else {Desktop = Desktop;}
```

Comment: Well you can start by getting rid of `else {Desktop = Desktop;}` which doesn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary operator and get rid of 4 lines.

```
var len = Desktop.split(', ').length;

Desktop = len === 4 ? 'All' : (len === 0 ? 'None' : Desktop);
```

Comment: this is not much shorter but definitely more elegant;)
Anyway this example, does not return the 'none'

Comment: @helderk it does.. If you look at the 2nd part of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

something like that will work more universally, not only if you have 4 checkboxes:

```
var max = $(".multiselect.desktop input[name$='[]']").length();
var $checked = $(".multiselect.desktop input[name$='[]']:checked");

var Desktop = ($checked.length() == max)?'All':($checked.length()?$checked.map(function() {return $(this).val();}).join(', '):'None');
```

Comment: This example is longer but really a good idea to catch the maximum number of checkboxes.
But also no returns which chekcboxes are selected when they are not all.

Comment: not longer, it's optimal, but adds max check, otherwise will be just 2 lines if you remove max and replace it with 4. When no selected items, it will return 'None' ... `$checked.length()?$checked.map(...).join(', '):'None'`. if max - will retuen 'All', if different will return comma separated string of checked box values.